# Context menu (righ click or toolbar) does not display anything on visual studio code Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ide, virtualbox

I did not find any answer on google, forum

I installed an Ubuntu VirtualBox on my Windows 10, and Visual Studio Code, but I have a problem with the context menu (right click or toolbar), when I start Visual Studio Code, it works, but after 2 minutes, it does not display anything

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUuip.png)

The problem may appear earlier, instantly when I open the terminal

I tried to uninstall Visual studio code and reinstall it, I tried to install another version of visual studio code but nothing

I am aware that having to execute everything in shortcut can be useful but I would very much like to find a solution!

Looking forward to an answer !